# The square root of an element preserves order in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I have no idea about this problem:

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $x,y$ are self-adjoint elements. Show that if $0 \leq x \leq y$, then $x^{1 / 2} \leq y^{1 / 2}$, where $x^{1/2}$ denotes the unique square root of $x$.

where the partial order $\leq$ is defined as below:
$$x \leq y \iff y-x \text{ is a positive element}$$
and a positive element $a$ is an element that can be expressed as $a = b^* b$ for some $b \in \mathcal{A}$.

I've learned the basic concepts about $C^*$-algebras and the continuous functional calculus, but I have no idea how to apply the theory here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has almost certainly been asked on this site before. Search square root operator monotone.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy Thank you I will give it a try.

Comment: Here are a couple: [first one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734008/square-root-of-positive-elements-preserve-order/1734432#1734432) , [second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246704/show-that-0-le-a-frac12-le-b-frac12?noredirect=1).